# MongoDB array of substrings and Aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'am working with MongoDB aggregation pipeline , as you can see , I have filtered the movie collection looking for movies that have won oscars. However, since the awards string comes with more info then I need , I have split it.

Now, I don't know I can keep only the substring which equals to the amount of Oscars won.

Could any one give me a hand ?

```
db.movies.aggregate([{$match : {"awards" : /Won . Oscar*/}}, {$sort: {"awards" : -1}}, {$project : {title : 1 , number_of_oscars:{$split:["$awards", "."]}, _id : 0} }]).pretty()
```

[image: Array of substrings]

What I want is to have something like :

```
{
"title" : "The Best Years of Our Lives ,
"number_of_oscars" : "Won 7 Oscars"

}
```

Data structure :

```
{
        {
        "_id" : ObjectId("573a1393f29313caabcdd0e5"),
        "title" : "The Best Years of Our Lives",
        "year" : 1946,
        "runtime" : "The Best Years of Our Lives",
        "released" : ISODate("1947-06-17T00:00:00Z"),
        "cast" : [
                "Fredric March",
                "Dana Andrews",
                "Teresa Wright",
                "Myrna Loy"
        ],
        "poster" : "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk1NTAxNzg3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjU4OTQwNw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "plot" : "Three WWII veterans return home to small-town America to discover that they and their families have been irreparably changed.",
        "fullplot" : "The story concentrates on the social re-adjustment of three World War II servicemen, each from a different station of society. Al Stephenson returns to an influential banking position, but finds it hard to reconcile his loyalties to ex-servicemen with new commercial realities. Fred Derry is an ordinary working man who finds it difficult to hold down a job or pick up the threads of his marriage. Having had both hands burnt off during the war, Homer Parrish is unsure that his fianc�e's feelings are still those of love and not those of pity. Each of the veterans faces a crisis upon his arrival, and each crisis is a microcosm of the experiences of many American warriors who found an alien world awaiting them when they came marching home.",
        "awards" : "Won 7 Oscars. Another 14 wins & 1 nomination.",
        "lastupdated" : "2015-09-17 01:24:38.307000000",
        "type" : "movie",
        "languages" : [
                "English"
        ],
        "directors" : [
                "William Wyler"
        ],
        "writers" : [
                "Robert E. Sherwood (screen play)",
                "MacKinlay Kantor (from a novel by)"
        ],
        "imdb" : {
                "rating" : 8.2,
                "votes" : 36573,
                "id" : 36868
        },
        "countries" : [
                "USA"
        ],
        "rated" : "PASSED",
        "genres" : [
                "Drama",
                "War",
                "Romance"
        ],
        "tomatoes" : {
                "viewer" : {
                        "rating" : 4.2,
                        "numReviews" : 10304,
                        "meter" : 92
                },
                "dvd" : ISODate("1997-10-30T00:00:00Z"),
                "rotten" : 1,
                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2015-09-17T17:19:13Z"),
                "consensus" : "An engrossing look at the triumphs and travails of war veterans, The Best Years of Our Lives is concerned specifically with the aftermath of World War II, but its messages speak to the overall American experience.",
                "critic" : {
                        "rating" : 8.6,
                        "numReviews" : 46,
                        "meter" : 98
                },
                "production" : "RKO Radio Pictures",
                "fresh" : 45
        },
        "num_mflix_comments" : 3,
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "name" : "April Hunt",
                        "email" : "april_hunt@fakegmail.com",
                        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1393f29313caabcdd0e5"),
                        "text" : "Inventore odio dolor quis provident maiores cum. Eum eaque placeat a dolores molestias tenetur. Velit velit adipisci quo eum corrupti.",
                        "date" : ISODate("2011-02-12T01:16:25Z")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Larry Smith Jr.",
                        "email" : "larry_smith_jr.@fakegmail.com",
                        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1393f29313caabcdd0e5"),
                        "text" : "Dolores facere vero saepe harum. Voluptas molestias alias magnam harum reiciendis eveniet. Eum molestiae facilis eveniet ex cumque harum.",
                        "date" : ISODate("2002-03-26T09:23:37Z")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Dana Cross",
                        "email" : "dana_cross@fakegmail.com",
                        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1393f29313caabcdd0e5"),
                        "text" : "Quae reprehenderit veritatis hic ex neque. Ad vero corrupti dolorem dolor optio voluptatum occaecati. Beatae fuga vero impedit iste. Eligendi ratione perferendis velit deleniti sit.",
                        "date" : ISODate("1970-07-17T05:42:03Z")
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Gregor Clegane",
                        "email" : "hafthór_júlíus_björnsson@gameofthron.es",
                        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1393f29313caabcdd6b8"),
                        "text" : "Porro nihil maxime magnam inventore placeat ad sequi. Placeat ullam officia delectus pariatur ab fuga aspernatur praesentium. Laudantium omnis ducimus quibusdam enim vel vitae.",
                        "date" : ISODate("1983-02-09T05:47:19Z")
                }
        ],
        "metacritic" : null,
        "num_mflix_commenents" : 4
}
```

Thank you

Comment: post example document and expected result in json format, don't post screenshots.

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Hi , i have updated the question with Data structure and expected result. I just want to select only one of the substrings I got with $split.

i have MongoDB shell version v4.4.5

Comment: you can use the below command to fetch the first element of array in `$project` stage `number_of_oscars: {$arrayElemAt: [{$split:["$awards", "."]}, 0]}`.  Let me know if you want a complete solution.